# question about stack and list for F#

Tags: f#

is stack is the same with List in F#? what about stack and sequence in F#? and what about queue?

Comment: Which "stack" and "queue" types are you referring to?

Comment: List in F# are singly linked list.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sequence in F# is a lazily evaluated chain of objects, sort-of like IEnumerable

Here's a [book](http://www.ctocorner.com/fsharp/book/ch10.aspx) to read.  And [another one](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/F_Sharp_Programming/Mutable_Collections#Stack.3C.27T.3E_Class).

Quoting:
The Stack<'T> class can be thought of as a mutable version of the F# list.

Comment: Not just "sort-of like IEnumerable". `seq<'T>` is an an alias for `IEnumerable<'T>` - they're the same type.

Comment: @Joel: Good point, but i did not find anything so specific in the spec: http://projects.ext.haxnet.org/~super/code/fsharp/FSharp-2.0-Language-Specification-2010-Apr.PDF  Could seq<T> be implementing more than just IEnumerable<T> in the future?

Comment: We should be sure we're talking about the same thing. A [sequence expression](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd233209.aspx) is a particular kind of computation expression that generates a `seq<'T>`. Other computation expressions do other things, but `seq<'T>` is really just an alias for `IEnumerable<'T>`. So sequence expressions might someday return an object that implements more than one interface, but I doubt that `seq<'T>` will change.

Answer (score 7):

Stacks and queues are *abstract data types* which can be implemented in several different ways. An F# list is implemented as an immutable singly-linked list. Since prepending or deleting an item from the front of a singly-linked list is a constant-time operation, F# lists make a good *representation* of a stack. But appending to a list is linear-time so they are less suitable for queues.

If you need an *ephemeral* stack then you might as well use the built-in `System.Collections.Generic.Stack<T>`. For a *persistent* stack, you could implement it yourself. This interface might be a good start:

```
type IStack<'A> =
    abstract member Push : 'A -> IStack<'A>
    abstract member Pop : unit -> 'A * IStack<'A>
```

or as a recursive data type:

```
type Stack<'A> = Stack of 'A * Stack<'A> | Empty
```

But to try and answer your question, although stacks and F# lists are not the same, lists are pervasive in functional programming and, because of their performance characteristics, they are used in places where a C# programmer would naturally reach for a stack. Since they are persistent, they are also a better fit for functional programs (which transform immutable data structures rather than modify mutable ones).

Answer (score 0):

If you mean stack and queues that are learned in a typical data structures course, then F# list and them are totally different.

Comment: yes, i mean that.. it seems stack have a same behaviour with List in F# doesn't it?

Comment: you can use F# List to simulate a stack, but not possible for a queue.